# Python for loop: iteration not complete

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to use the following function in order mutate the elements of two lists:
If a list element starts with a "U", the element should be mutated to "1", otherwise the list element should be mutated to "0".
Here is the code:

```
def measure(p):
    for x in range(len(p)):
        if p[x][0] == 'U':
            p[x] = 1
        else:
            p[x] = 0
        return p

print measure(['Dave','Sebastian','Katy'])
print measure(['Umika','Umberto'])
```

The correct result should be

```
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 1]
```

But the current code produces:

```
[0, 'Sebastian', 'Katy']
[1, 'Umberto']
```

It seems that the iteration stopped after the first element. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your function terminates after the first loop, because of " return p" statement

Answer (score 4):

Your function terminates after the first loop, because you have an unconditional return inside that loop. Move the return to the outside of the loop.

```
def measure(p):
    for x in range(len(p)):
        if p[x][0] == 'U':
            p[x] = 1
        else:
            p[x] = 0
    return p

print measure(['Dave','Sebastian','Katy'])
print measure(['Umika','Umberto'])
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 1]
```

Comment: `return [0 if x[0] != 'U' else 1 for x in p]`

Answer (score 0):

Know that `return` always terminates a function when executed. In the first loop of your `for` loop, your function executes the `return` statement and end the function `measure`. That's why only the first element of `p` is changed to 0 or 1.

Just put the `return` statement outside the for loop

```
def measure(p):
    for x in range(len(p)):
        if p[x][0] == 'U':
            p[x] = 1
        else:
            p[x] = 0
    return p
```

Answer (score 0):

As a bonus, your function is quite simple, and can be made in a one-liner as follow:

```
def f(L):
    return [1 if elt[0].lower() == "u" else 0 for elt in L]

f(['Umika','Umberto'])
Out[27]: [1, 1]

f(['Dave','Sebastian','Katy'])
Out[28]: [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The identation of the return statement is inside the for loop. That means the code stops after modifying only the first element.

Put the return statement at the same identation level as the for statement and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is indented too far - that's why it is stopping after the first element. It should be indented at the same level as the `for x...` line. Try:

```
>>> def measure(p):
...     for x in range(len(p)):
...         if p[x][0] == 'U':
...             p[x] = 1
...         else:
...             p[x] = 0
...     return p
...
>>> print measure(['Dave','Sebastian','Katy'])
[0, 0, 0]
>>> print measure(['Umika','Umberto'])
[1, 1]
```